# Google Code changing host fingerprint causes hg pull to fail

Tags: mercurial, https, repository, google-code, fingerprint

I'm using Google code and Mercurial for a small project [javaclass-rb](http://code.google.com/p/javaclass-rb/). I cloned the repository using HTTPS. My `.hg/hgrc` contains

```
[paths]
default = https://javaclass-rb.googlecode.com/hg/
```

From time to time Google Code has a different fingerprint (most likely to the clustering of service). When I want to pull (with hg 1.8.4), I get

```
E:\Develop\JavaClass>hg pull -u
abort: invalid certificate for javaclass-rb.googlecode.com with fingerprint 28:92:6b:9b:40:10:cc:0e:4c:16:a4:78:7f:bb:1a:8d:d4:d1:d3:27
```

Then I have to change my `~/.hgrc` file and update the `hostfingerprints`section to contain the new fingerprint:

```
[hostfingerprints]
javaclass-rb.googlecode.com = 28:92:6b:9b:40:10:cc:0e:4c:16:a4:78:7f:bb:1a:8d:d4:d1:d3:27
```

Then everything works fine again, until next time. Now this gets annoying as I did it ten times already, approx. once a month, and have to do it on several machines (desktop, laptop, work pc etc.)...

```
34:4b:90:e7:e3:36:81:0d:52:1f:10:c0:4c:98:66:90:4a:9e:05:c9
6e:a8:09:6a:42:60:d7:81:f7:04:b8:0f:5d:1e:ac:b3:58:db:7e:da
89:6d:fb:e5:4a:7e:72:91:db:0b:ee:72:9f:60:a7:29:65:fd:e1:10
da:b3:df:aa:55:73:ac:65:04:70:78:8e:ed:dd:a9:be:40:a8:64:81
a9:be:c0:4a:da:1c:eb:4c:31:9d:78:27:48:99:f4:9c:9a:e8:53:c8
ed:19:7c:b9:a3:48:27:93:72:74:43:db:26:40:af:e0:7a:90:1c:97
28:92:6b:9b:40:10:cc:0e:4c:16:a4:78:7f:bb:1a:8d:d4:d1:d3:27
```

**Do you know a way to configure Mercurial to ignore the fingerprints or some other way I get rid of this annoyance?**

**Answer**

tonfa led me on the right track. Mercurial is [checking also OS certificates](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates). Originally I had to fall back to fingerprints because Googlecode certiicate is not valid for subdomains:

```
The certificate is only valid for the following names:
  *.googlecode.com , *.u.googlecode.com , googlecode.com , *.codespot.com , *.googlesource.com , googlesource.com
```

1) I removed the fingerprints from `.hgrc`, then the top domain `javaclass-rb.googlecode.com` worked again, because it is matched by `*.googlecode.com`.

2) Subdomains have to be cloned with another name, see [Google support](https://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=5661).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the fingerprints and not verifying the signature is a **very** bad idea.

You should follow the instructions at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates (basically a recent version of TortoiseHg should be already correctly configured).

Comment: Ah, OK - for some reason I'd assumed that normal certificate validation wasn't working and the OP had to use fingerprints for some reason.

Comment: Yes, the original problem was `The certificate is only valid for the following names:
  *.googlecode.com , *.u.googlecode.com , googlecode.com , *.codespot.com , *.googlesource.com , googlesource.com` so I fell back to fingerprints. But these are changing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command `hg pull --insecure`.

Comment: that indeed is a very bad idea!

Comment: After learning about man in the middle attacks over the years since I posted this answer, I have to agree with you.

Comment: Great. Please still leave your answer there, so others see that it's a theoretical possibility and further why it is a bad idea ;)